# WP Paths in a Plugin - how to include

Tags: plugins, paths

I'm working on my first WP plugin, and I'm having trouble getting a file include to work. My directory structure looks like this:

- myPlugin

  - classes
  - templates
  - css
  - js
- myplugin.php

My main plugin file (`myplugin.php`) includes / requires various files in the classes directory, and that works fine. However, one of the files in the classes directory is *supposed* to include a file from the templates directory. I've tried everything I can think of, from `plugins_url()` to `plugin_basename()` to `plugin_dir_path()` but nothing seems to work.

How should this statement look to get it to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in the main plugin file (`myplugin.php`):

```
defined( 'MY_PLUGIN_URL' ) || define( 'MY_PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) );
defined( 'MY_PLUGIN_PATH' ) || define( 'MY_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) );
```

right before any other code, and use `MY_PLUGIN_PATH` to include files, or `MY_PLUGIN_URL` to load your assets.

E.G:

- `require_once MY_PLUGIN_PATH . 'templates/se.php';`
- `wp_enqueue_style( 'my-css', MY_PLUGIN_URL . 'assets/css/style.css' );`

Those constants can be accessible from any other file including the main plugin loader file and the files within the sub-directories. As long as the plugin is loaded correctly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Samuel - exactly what I was trying to think of. Worked like a charm!